# Extract words, from string, into list | Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I have read quite a few posts but with no luck.

I have tried both `.split()` and `regex` so far.

Note: I am running this code on [repl.it/](https://replit.com/).

```
import math

documents = [
  ["It is going to rain today"],
  ["Today I am not going outside"],
  ["I am going to watch the season premiere"]
]
docs = 1000
words_per_doc = 100  # length of doc

dp = 4

# -- Setup --
all_words = []  # all instances
for doc in documents:
  for s in doc:
     words = s.split()
     print(words)
  all_words.append(words)
all_words = sorted(all_words)  # alphabeticalise
all_words = list(dict.fromkeys(all_words))  # remove duplicates

print('All Words')
print(all_words)
print()


print('Binary Scoring')
for doc in documents:
  scoring = []
  for word in all_words:
    if word in doc:
      scoring.append(1)
    else:
      scoring.append(0)
  print("\"" + doc + "\" = " + scoring)
print()
```

Error:

```
['It', 'is', 'going', 'to', 'rain', 'today']
['Today', 'I', 'am', 'not', 'going', 'outside']
['I', 'am', 'going', 'to', 'watch', 'the', 'season', 'premiere']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import BagofWords
  File "/home/runner/DeepLearning/BagofWords.py", line 21, in <module>
    all_words = list(dict.fromkeys(all_words))  # remove duplicates
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You don't have a list of strings, you have a list of lists. Is there a reason for that? Might the sublists have more than one string in them?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Split seems to work just fine

```
   for doc in documents:
       words=doc[0].split(' ')
       print(words)
```

You wrote the whole code wrong

Here is the correct code

```
import re
import math

documents = [
  ["It is going to rain today"],
  ["Today I am not going outside"],
 ["I am going to watch the season premiere"]
]
docs = 1000
words_per_doc = 100  # length of doc

dp = 4

# -- Setup --
all_words = []  # all instances
for doc in documents: 
  words=doc[0].split(' ')
  print(words)
  all_words.append(words)

 print('All Words')
 print(all_words)
print()


print('Binary Scoring')
for doc in documents:
scoring = 0
for word in all_words[0]:
    if word in doc[0]:
        scoring = scoring + 1
    else:
        scoring = scoring

print("\"" + doc[0] + "\" = " + str(scoring))
```

Comment: Check the updated code. Code works for first item in list if you need other items in list too just loop it through

Answer (score 0):

Full working code:

```
import math
import itertools

documents = [
  ["It is going to rain today"],
  ["Today I am not going outside"],
  ["I am going to watch the season premiere"]
]
docs = 1000
words_per_doc = 100  # length of doc

dp = 4

# -- Setup --
all_words = []  # all instances
for doc in documents:
  for s in doc:
     words = s.split()
     print(words)
     all_words.append(words)
all_words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_words))
all_words = sorted(all_words)  # alphabeticalise
all_words = list(dict.fromkeys(all_words))

print(all_words, "\n")

print('Binary Scoring')
for doc in documents:
  scoring = []
  for word in all_words:
    if word in doc[0]:
      scoring.append(1)
    else:
      scoring.append(0)
  print("\"" + doc + "\" = " + scoring)
```

See explanation in my other answer.

Comment: I still get an error :(. I have pasted the new error output above. Maybe it's to do with my environment?

Comment: @iNeedHelp Should work now, have another go

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working either. Make sure you're running it in a fresh environment too, like I am.

Answer (score -1):

You have a list of list of strings so you must loop through the inner lists in order to get the strings (I assume the inner lists can be of any length).

```
for doc in documents:
  for s in doc:
     words = s.split()
     print(words)
```

will get the words spitted from every document and print them.

Output:

```
['It', 'is', 'going', 'to', 'rain', 'today']
['Today', 'I', 'am', 'not', 'going', 'outside']
['I', 'am', 'going', 'to', 'watch', 'the', 'season', 'premiere']
```

Comment: This still throws an error. I have appended my whole code above.

Comment: Using nested lists so as I can copy and paste sentences into it easily in one run

Comment: @iNeedHelp remove any `re` because you do not need it, I tested the above code and it works.